# Bootsrap 3: Responsive breakpoint from rows of 3 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two rows which contain 3 column each , I would like at certain breakpoint to switch from 3 columns to 2 column and from 2 columns to 1 column (mobile breakpoint). so far this is what I have.

```css
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .col-md-4{
        min-width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-md-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
```

> ***Question***

***This does not work , what am I missing in my code? help am newbie though***

Comment: you should not redefine the col-md-4 class but better use different col definitions https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match

Comment: Thank you lars for this , Now I understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would place them all in the same `.row` and use the appropriate grid classes. This should get you what you want:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
```

Note: I would **not** redefine `.col-md-4` or any of the Bootstrap built-in grid glasses like that.

For more details, read the Bootstrap documentation on using grid glasses: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match

Comment: clear and quick solution without combination ma nigga thank you , hope england will win today :D :D :D

Comment: I have another simple question , I want in such a way that when placed in a single row, the second product is under the third product. how can I archiev that?

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana look into column ordering: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: is it possible to archieve that using media query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156230/ordering-classes-in-bootstrap-3/51156378?noredirect=1#comment89296410_51156378

Answer (score 3):

Just use the different breakpoint column classes of bootstrap.
If you want to change order in bootstrap 3 (as requested in comments) you can easily use push and pull.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">3</div>
    </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match

Comment: lars: I have another simple question , I want in such a way that when placed in a single row, the second product is under the third product. how can I archieve that?

Comment: actually the best way to go would be to order the elements as they should be in mobile first, then change the order in the other viewports (where they ar next to each other). There are different possibilities to do this - also depending which bootstrap version you use... if you use 4.x just read this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

Comment: am using bootstrap 3

Comment: than take a look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering you can just change the order when they are next to each other be pushing and pulling them

Comment: `"col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-push-6"  and "col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-pull-6" ` do you mean something like this? i tried too still does not work :(

Comment: here is fiddle I have created https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/7pdLexjk/ check it does not work

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: thanks lars i have solution that does not work , i used flex with order then everything works fine u can check it on the link above how the solution look

Comment: ok... bootstrap 4 would have used that by default for the rows :) so flexbox is a good solution

Answer (score 2):

**Use `col-sm-6` to set 2 divs in 1 row on `sm` size...**

(the calc is: `12/6=2 => 100% /2=50%` means each div gets `50%` to his `width`)

**By default in `xs` size's screen will set 1 div in 1 row because you did not specify otherwise...**

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">3</div>
</div>

<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more explaintions

Comment: This won't work quite right in .sm since the 6 divs are split across 2 rows. See my answer.

Comment: you right but the OP use it as is so I use his code :)