# Ordering classes in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have simple container with one row which holds 6 elements (divs). I am struggling to reorder elements using media query.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        .product2{
          order: 3;
        }
        .products{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row products">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product1">product1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product2">product2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product3">product3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product4">product4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product5">product5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product6">product6</div>
    </div>
```

I want in such a way that when placed in a single row, the second product is under the third product.

When I run my app displays reordered element but instead of product2 being placed at the place of the third product its placed in last element as product6.

What is wrong with my codes? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID's. In CSS there is a thing called specificity which basically means, which rule holds most weight (and gets applied).

Change your HTML to:

```
 <div class="row products">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="product1">product1</div>

    <!-- rest of divs -->
</div>
```

and css to:

```
div#product1 {
    /** your rules **/
}
```

this will override class stylings.

here's MDN docs on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

## update after re-reading question

you want to use `push` and `pull` classes:

so your HTML becomes

```
 <div class="row products">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-push-12" id="product1">product1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-pull-12" id="product2">product2</div>

    <!-- rest of divs -->
</div>
```

This will push `product1` underneath `product2` on `sm` viewports, read all about it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: stil does not work, displays as before as the last element ,

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana did you remove your media query / change `col-sm` to `col-xs` ?

Comment: actualy your answer did not say anything about that, here is fiddle can you check it , I have tried something similar but still not working https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/7pdLexjk/4/

Comment: @Kaczkapojebana yes it does - my code is a template answer, not a copy/paste solution - it aims to educate not be copied

Comment: okay, I checked the link you gave and tried to do as per instruction you can see it in my fiddle maybe I am missing something

Comment: I have updated the fiddle , but even in my local machine that does not work , that is why i created the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if some one will be interested.
Works perfect as I wanted. thanks all for the support
Html

```
<div class="row products">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product1">product1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product2">product2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product3">product3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product4">product4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product5">product5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 product" id="product6">product6</div>
    </div>
```

css

```
   @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        .products{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
.product:nth-of-type(1) { order: 1; }
.product:nth-of-type(2) { order: 3; }
.product:nth-of-type(3) { order: 2; }
.product:nth-of-type(4) { order: 4; }
.product:nth-of-type(5) { order: 5; }
.product:nth-of-type(6) { order: 6; }

}
```